# How to update record in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanna update product quantity in php, by the way I use pdo.
There is a button to update quantity. 
But the problem is when first I clicked the button to update quantity(jumlah) the database getting update, but when I clicked again and again and again.. the quantity still same, there's no change at all. It should be when I clcik that button, quantity will increase to one.

update.php

```
$id_penjualan=$row['id_penjualan'];
$query="select * from tb_detail_penjualan,tb_buku where tb_buku.id_buku=tb_detail_penjualan.id_buku and tb_detail_penjualan.id_buku='$_GET[id_buku]'";
$stmt=$con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(":id_penjualan"=>$id_penjualan));
$stmt->execute();
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($row>0){
    $id_buku=$row['id_buku'];
    $harga=$row['harga'];
    $jumlah=$row['jumlah'];
    $jmltambah=$jumlah+1; //problem
    $subtotaltambah = $jmltambah * $harga;
    $penjualan->update_detail_penjualan($jmltambah,$subtotaltambah,$id_penjualan,$id_buku,$id_pelanggan);
```

class_penjualan.php

```
public function update_detail_penjualan($jmltambah,$subtotaltambah,$id_penjualan,$id_buku,$id_pelanggan)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE tb_detail_penjualan SET jumlah=:jmltambah, subtotal=:subtotaltambah WHERE id_penjualan=:id_penjualan 
                                                AND id_buku=:id_buku AND id_pelanggan=:id_pelanggan");
            $stmt->bindparam(":jmltambah", $jmltambah);
            $stmt->bindparam(":subtotaltambah", $subtotaltambah);
            $stmt->bindparam(":id_penjualan",$id_penjualan);
            $stmt->bindparam(":id_buku",$id_buku);
            $stmt->bindparam(":id_pelanggan",$id_pelanggan);

            $stmt->execute();

            return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `bindparam` that should read as `bindParam`. 99% of the time, it requires an uppercase "P".

Comment: yes @Fred-ii- Is right.

Comment: add `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` right after the connection is opened. You'll most likely see something like "doesn't match number of binds blah blah blah"... - `catch (PDOException $e)` isn't always enough.

Comment: plus, in your update.php file, you're not binding anything to `:id_penjualan`, so that's failing right off the bat.

Comment: In my connection.php I've use setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) and before $id_penjualan=$row['id_penjualan']; I have put another script, I put the important script here I think... @ Fred -ii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of doing it in PHP

```
$jmltambah=$jumlah+1;
```

You can do it right in your SQL query

```
UPDATE tb_detail_penjualan SET jumlah= jumlah + 1 ...
```

Comment: Thank you meda it work. I changed update script to unusual pdo. but can you tell me how to make it work in oop pdo  too ? 'cause all my scripts use oop pdo.
  
Thank you so much meda..

Comment: @Ayuktia this is it. PDO only has OOP, it is mysqli that has the procedural way.

Comment: so, my new script using mysqli even the connection witn pdo ..??

Comment: This code you posted is using pdo you cannot mix both